# DatePicker onDateChanged called twice

Tags: android, datepicker

I have a `DatePicker` inside a `Fragment`, inside a `ViewPager`.

evertime i make a change, i see the event firing twice.

Is this common?

here s my code:

```
public class CreateWishFormDatePaginationFragment extends Fragment implements DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener {


    public static CreateWishFormDatePaginationFragment newInstance(int position) {
        Log.i("PaginationFragment#", " CreateWishFormDatePaginationFragment called for fragment : " + position);
        CreateWishFormDatePaginationFragment fragment = new CreateWishFormDatePaginationFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(KEY_POSITION, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // ... (omitted)
        dateDeparture.init(dateDepartureInit.get(Calendar.YEAR), dateDepartureInit.get(Calendar.MONTH), dateDepartureInit.get(Calendar.DATE), this);
    }



    @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i2, int i3) {

            if (datePicker.isShown()) {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                c.set(i, i2, i3);
                Log.d("PaginationFragment#", "onDateChanged: " + c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                listener.onFormDateEvent(CriterionName.DATE_DEPARTURE, c, iPosition);
                txtDepartureWeekday.setText(c.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.ENGLISH));
            }
        }
}
```

Logs:

```
03-04 15:13:01.238  28352-28352/org.intracode.shoppingalertsystem.app D/PaginationFragment#﹕ onDateChanged: 2016
...
03-04 15:13:01.241  28352-28352/org.intracode.shoppingalertsystem.app D/PaginationFragment#﹕ onDateChanged: 2016
```

Any other control doesnT fire twice.

Comment: Have a look at this hope this will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28826557/datepicker-in-4-3-is-setting-the-date-even-when-clicked-on-cancel-button/28826579#28826579

Comment: it s not in a dialog.i think it s not related

Comment: I'm having the same issue